# VS2017 NuGet 'Get-Package -ListAvailable' fails once solution opened

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

In VS2017 Community Edition (fresh install, started in admin mode), I can run 'Get-Package -ListAvailable' from the PM> prompt, no problem; it displays maybe 50 packages.

I then open a Solution (SQLCLR project).

Running 'Get-Package -ListAvailable' from the PM> prompt, I now get in red font:

```
Get-Package : Project 'Default' is not found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Package -ListAvailable
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Default:String) [Get-Package], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetProjectNotFound,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.GetPackageCommand
```

How do I fix this?
BTW I actually want to install something that fails in a similar way, but tried to narrow down the failure to something as simple to duplicate as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> then open a Solution (SQLCLR project).
>   Running 'Get-Package -ListAvailable' from the PM> prompt, I now get in red font:

That is because **sql project is not supported by nuget** now. If you right click on your solution, you will find the "Manage NuGet package for solution" and "Restore NuGet Packages" are grey.

[image]

NuGet should show the message "this project is not supported" instead of "Project 'Default' is not found". And Nuget team is doing this thing.
For the detail information, you can refer to [Issue 1215](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1215) for detail.

**Update**:

To fix this issue, we have already submit this requirement to Visual Studio User Voice of "Manage NuGet Packages should support Database project". [Here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/15269538-manage-nuget-packages-should-support-database-proj) is the feedback. You can vote and add your comments for this feedback. When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.

Comment: It looks like the 'fix' will actually be just changing the error message. Well, at least the new message should make it clear that I'm not able to use NuGet.

Comment: @brewmanz, I have updated my answer with a User Voice for supporting Database project, you can check it. If above answer resolve your question, you can mark it as answer which is benefit for other communities who has the same problem. If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue? Thanks.

Comment: thanks for that. Marked as an answer as I guess it's as close as we get for the moment.